# Titanium studo error android emulator run

Tags: android, ide, titanium, appcelerator

I have a fresh install of Appcelerator Titanium Studio, Java, Python, and Node. When I import any of the sample projects and try to run on my android phone or in the emulator I get this error and log out put:

```
Error:
'Launching Titanium Android Emulator - Geocoder' has encountered a problem.

A problem has occured
```

Details are blank.

```
Log:
!ENTRY com.aptana.core 4 -1073741819 2013-05-23 19:22:28.667
!MESSAGE
```

The message portion of the log is blank.

any one ever run into this and have a suggestion of how to fix it?